# Для чего в расширении файла есть дополнительные символы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Увидел на сайте подключённые стили с названием site_global.css@crc=91730608, такая же история с файлами js. Для чего служат эти дополнительные символы?

Comment: Для инвалидации кеша. ПС. В интернете нет расширений. Только http-адреса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тем самым Вы подсказываете браузеру, что нужно заново скачать файл.

Например, пользователь первый раз заходит на Ваш сайт. Браузер видит вот такой путь site_global.css@crc=**91730608**. Кладёт файл в браузерный кеш. 
Зайдя второй раз на сайт спустя время этот CSS-файл возьмётся из браузерного кеша. Для Вас это очень хорошо, так как не будет http-запроса и ожидания загрузки файла, но что делать если Вы добавили новые правила в CSS?
В этом случае вам нужно поменять путь до файла и это можно сделать с помощью другого http-запроса, например site_global.css@crc=**91730610**. Физически это будет все тот же `site_global.css`, но http-запрос уже будет новым и браузер решит, что нужно скачать новый файл.